# Replace all .png to nothing in python

Tags: python, string, replace, replaceall, python-re

```
import re
s="fig shown abcd.png referring 12254383.png"
p=re.sub("\(.*?).png\", '', s)
print(p)
```

Output expected:
fig shown referring

Please help to remove *.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of the regex that works:

https://regex101.com/r/HJLzTo/1

```
pat = re.compile(r'[\w]+\.png')
pat.sub('', "fig shown abcd.png referring 12254383.png")
```

Result:

```
'fig shown  referring '
```